# Fairly deep phrase meaning

Tags: meaning, grammar, phrases, context

I'm having difficulty with understanding this phrase:

> sorry, I've been in a fairly deep recently

Is this statement cut off as not making greater sense to me? That was a response to my message.

Comment: It's not a standard phrase, just something off the cuff, and maybe with a typo (the "a" is unexpected). It means "sorry I haven't been responsive, I've been quite busy".

Comment: Thanks so much for quick response. Your suggestion makes sense to the overall situation.

Comment: If it were in a spoken context (vocal message), I wonder if one   could interpret  "a" as "huh", a mark of hesitation?

Answer (score 3):

To be "in deep" can be understood as:

> inextricably involved in or committed to a situation. "He knew that he
>   was in deep when his things began to proliferate in her apartment"

Your sentence looks like a variation on it. Sometimes, a "strong" or negative word is omitted in spoken sentences, which in   this situation could have been depression, as suggested, or illness, trouble.

Source: [Oxford dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/deep)

Answer (score 2):

That looks like a typo. It doesn't mean anything. Looks like someone was writing something like

> I've been in a fairly deep depression

Comment: Thank you. It completes the above suggestion, somethings going on there, no doubts. Much appreciated.